# Skip ViewController

Tags: ios

If a user opens the app and then tab on the last `tabbar` item, it takes him to the `login viewcontroller`, the following it works. Either user register or enter his credentials, then he could able to see his `profile view controller`.  `TabBar[4]` indicates the last item in the `TabBar`

```
TabBar [4]  -> Nav Controller ->Login -> User Profile
```

However, what if a user already registered or logged in, how could I able to open the user `Profile ViewController` directly, in other words, how could I skip `Login viewcontoller`?

```
TabBar [4]  -> Nav Controller -> User Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You should skip initializing the `Nav Controller` as well.
When the user is *logged in*, the `User Profile` should be directly a member of the TabBar.
Consider some code like:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

// FirstViewController
First *firstVC = [[First alloc]init];
firstVC.title = @"First";
firstVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];

//SecondViewController
Second *secondVC = [[Second alloc] init];
secondVC.title = @"Second";
secondVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];

//ThirdViewController
Third *thirdVC = [[Third alloc] init];
thirdVC.title = @"Third";
thirdVC.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];

//The User Profile Screen
UserProfileVC *userProfile = [[UserProfileVC alloc] init];
userProfile.title = @"User Profile";
userProfile.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];

tabBar.viewControllers = @[firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC, userProfile];
```

Comment: could u please provide more detail? If I delete `Nav Controller` and directly connect the tabbar to `LogViewController`, then what would happen `TabBar image`? In the storyboard, you should set up the Tabbar image.

Comment: @hotspring Remember that you are _opening_ the app, so the `Nav Controller` should not even be created if the user is _logged in_. Check the edit, I've added a small snippet of how it would be programmatically.

Comment: you mean there will be no connection on the tabbar to loginviewcontroller or userprofileviewcontroller, rather do it programatically? I still do not get it. I have already set up all other viewcontrollers to the tabbar. The only one is allocated for login/userprofile which is connected via navigationcontroller.

Comment: @hotspring No, I'm implying that the `UINavigationController` can be omitted. The tabbar should directly control the Login & User Profile VC.

Comment: @hotspring  I may be missing some other scenarios here, would be great if you could share some related code base if your doubt still persists.